# Error Showing when validating my website

Tags: php

There is no attribute "height"

```
padding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="969" height="180">
```

I am getting this problem in the tpl files of my xcart version 4.4.2. How to resolve this problem? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This specifically? Delete the `height` attribute. It doesn't exist in the language you are using.

In general? Use CSS for presentation, not HTML.